# Circular Dependencies?

Tags: c++, dependencies

Okay, I understand forward declarations, but I need to call members / fields on BOTH ends in this case, so I can't use that. I tried to overwrite the declaration inside the .cpp file (by including the actual header of the class I need to use) but the pointer I defined in the header via forward declaration was broken when I tried to use it.

How can I get around this? Do you need code ?

Comment: The mutual dependency you describe indicates a design flaw. Revisit your design and eliminate the tight coupling between the two types.

Comment: An SSCCE would be lovely... http://sscce.org/

Comment: Well, I have an event system. I also have a class A which contains a pointer of an Object of Class B, and manages this object. Now I want Class B to send Events, containing a pointer to Class A. Thus all classes need to know each other (except for the Event class, it only needs to know class A)

Comment: Class B doesn't need to know the type of Class A in order to send events to it. Use dependency injection. Make Class A derive from a class called "EventReceiver", and then store a pointer to the EventReceiver in Class B. See [the Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: The events are not handled by either A or B. Class B needs to know "Event". "Event" needs to know class A. Class A needs to know class B.

Comment: And why does Event need to know class A?

Comment: Because class A contains a field which the Event requires. (Class A contains a player and other info, which is used by the event for logging & identification, Class A is a gamecontroller and class B is the game logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that forming a pointer to a class only requires a *declaration* of that class, while accessing that class's members requires its *definition.* So to solve circular dependencies, you can do this:

**A.hpp**

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
  int foo(B *b);
  int bar();
};
```

**B.hpp**

```
class A;

class B
{
  A *m_a;
public:
  int foo();
  explicit B(A *a) : m_a(a) {}
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

int A::foo(B *b)
{
  return 2 * b->foo();
}

int A::bar()
{
  return 42;
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

int B::foo()
{
  return m_a->bar();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the pointer was invalid (memory exception)

Comment: AHH! You're right, I misnamed a variable!

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one that will have access to the inside of the code (like when you're doing a project for yourself, alone, or distributing a closed *.lib/*.dll), and you're **sure** you need your classes to include themselves in a circular way, you could always use an abstract base class.

```
class base{};

class A: public base{
   base *bMember;
};

class B: public base{
   base *aMember;
};
```

That's a bit of a bad practice, but if you need a straight solution, it should be sufficient. A better way would be to fix the dependencies or use separate base classes.

Comment: Even if he did really need to do this, why wouldn't forward declarations suffice? I don't see the point of the abstract base class.

Comment: Some older IDE's tend to ignore forward declarations. I had a problem like that when I was doing a project long ago with some version of VS.